# Cannot download to network drive in TBs?

Tags: router, download, network-drive

I try to download a file in 1.2TB size to my book live drive. I connected to it via wireless network. However, I cannot download all the file and after a while of download, download speed just diminished to 0. In addition I can install any file in hundreds of GBs. I cannot point out the problem but thinking about limitations of the wireless router. Can router cause the problem or what you think?

As an additional problem that I realize, if I open the download of many different file concurrently again all the downloads stops suddenly and I cannot go into internet unless I restart the router

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a definitive answer online, but it sounds to me very much like this could be a limitation on the size of a single file of a drive.  (Apparently it uses EXT4, however an EXT4 maximum filesize can range from 16 Gigs to way larger then 2tb, so it depends on how its formatted).

While it could be a problem with the router, I think that is less likely, as the router is simply forwarding packets.